# Can I restrict google places autocomplete to city, town and neighborhoods?

Tags: javascript, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

Right now I'm using 'geocode' but that allows me to use addresses, cities, towns, and larger. Like states and countries.

Can I limit the results to just neighborhoods, cities and towns? Eliminating specific addresses and anything larger than cities like states and countries?

ex. this is for a social net site where I gather location data for each user. I want them to be as specific as possible without giving exact locations (ex. address) and not too large as that it would make searching for them impossible (ex. state, country)

Here is what I'm currently doing.

```js
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.element, {
  types: ['geocode']
  // types: ['(cities)']
});
```

Comment: One trick you can do is to limit the search to the current view, that may work so the only prediction the user will get will be around the area in view only.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? What do you mean by current view?

Comment: The code will  be something like this in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction)